# Ubuntu Linux does not detect my headphones; no voice input or output

Tags: detect

I have a Turtle Beach headset which I use a PC-Y splitter cable to connect into two line-in ports for voice and speakers for my headsets. This headset is not being detected at all.

When I check "Sound" in settings, there is no device for input and the three Outputs I have are:

- HDMI/DisplayPort-GP106 High Definition Audio COntroller
- DIgital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio
- Analogue Output - Built-in Audio

These are none of the outputs I believe my headset corresponds to. I would appreciate some help as I am a total beginner to LInux. On windows however, it is totally fine.

Thanks